# Python Lambda Package & Deploy Bash

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

From my buildspec.yml (within CodeBuild) I execute a bash file (code below), to copy, rename, zip, move, then upload 168 Python lambdas to S3. Average size of Lambda zip is 381KB.

Locally, Mac running Mojave 10.14, the bash executes successfully as expected, every time.

When running in the build container, Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 - aws/codebuild/standard:2.0), the script never fully succeeds, but does not throw an error either. At best, 5 - 9 zip files are uploaded into S3, if the script even gets that far.

I've tried a plethora of corrective actions, from optimizing the bash (e.g. not copying to _staging directory and not moving the zips) to employing copy instead of sync in the S3 upload, to increasing the environment compute power to max.

My only "clue" as to the issue is output begins to log when not expected. 
e.g.

```
Copying Lambdas to S3 Lambda Repository    
adding: psycopg2/psycopg1.py (deflated 56%) 
adding: psycopg2/__init__.py (deflated 65%)
```

instead of

```
Copying Lambdas to S3 Lambda Repository 
upload: _deploy/beta-forgot-password.zip to s3://beta-com-lambdas/20190731142007/beta-forgot-password.zip
upload: _deploy/beta-change-password.zip to s3://beta-com-lambdas/20190731142007/beta-change-password.zip
```

Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/bash
BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=$1
UNIQUE_KEY=$2
echo 'Executing Lambda Package and Deployment for: '$BUILD_ENVIRONMENT' environment';
echo 'Unique Lambda S3 Key: ' $UNIQUE_KEY
echo 'Creating Lambda Staging Directory';
mkdir ./_staging ;
echo 'Copying Lambdas to Staging Directory' ;
cp -r ./lambdas/* ./_staging;
echo 'Renaming Lambdas in Staging Directory' ;
cd _staging
for i in */; do mv "$i" "$BUILD_ENVIRONMENT-${i%/}" ; done
echo 'Zipping Lambdas in Staging Directory' ;
for i in */; do (cd "$i"; zip -r "../${i%/}.zip" .) &> /dev/null ;
echo "Zipping: ${i%/}.zip" ; done
echo 'Creating Lambda Deploy Directory' ;
mkdir ./_deploy ;
echo 'Moving Lambda Deployment Packages' ;
find . -name "*.zip" -exec mv {} ./_deploy \;
echo "Sync Lambdas to S3 Lambda Repository "
aws sync ./_deploy s3://$BUILD_ENVIRONMENT-smc-com-lambdas/$UNIQUE_KEY/
echo "Lambda Package and Deployment Completed"
```

Comment: Why don't you try to create your own "Build Environment" which is basically a Docker container. Check this blog post [Extending AWS CodeBuild with Custom Build Environments](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments/). If you can make it work on a container in your machine, it should work with CodeBuild and the same "Build Environment".

Comment: The bash script that you show here doesn't contain the line "Copying Lambdas to S3 Lambda Repository"; please post the correct script.

Comment: For what it's worth, the output on the first example looks like it's coming from zip, so I would suspect that you're running zip in the background and not all of the files are ready when you start the upload.

Comment: Thanks kdgregory & @guzmonne. I was able to resolve using the steps below.

Comment: @kdgregory - would have been worth a lot if I had seen it before inserting set -x and realizing the issue; but your hunch was spot on. Thank you again.